# Fancybox shows different effect (with scrollbar and no scrollbar) in server and localhost

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, lightbox

My problem is kinda weird. The effects shown differently in localhost and server as shown below. Please take note: I'm using the same code for both sides.

This code is uploaded to server. The fancybox is not scaled properly, and there is a scrollbar even though the content is short.
[image]

This code is opened in localhost/computer. The fancybox is scaled nicely to fit in viewport and no scrollbar.
[image]

Can someone please explain to me why? Is that any solution for my issue? Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
```

```css
.fancybox-wrap,
.fancybox-skin,
.fancybox-outer,
.fancybox-inner,
.fancybox-image,
.fancybox-wrap iframe,
.fancybox-wrap object,
.fancybox-nav,
.fancybox-nav span,
.fancybox-tmp
{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: none;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.fancybox-wrap {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 8020;
}

.fancybox-skin {
 position: relative;
 background: #f9f9f9;
 color: #444;
 text-shadow: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
         border-radius: 4px;
}

.fancybox-opened {
 z-index: 8030;
}

.fancybox-opened .fancybox-skin {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
         box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.fancybox-outer, .fancybox-inner {
 position: relative;
}

.fancybox-inner {
 overflow: hidden;
}

.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-inner {
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.fancybox-error {
 color: #444;
 font: 14px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 15px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.fancybox-image, .fancybox-iframe {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.fancybox-image {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}

#fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
 background-image: url('../images/fancybox_sprite.png');
}

#fancybox-loading {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -22px;
 margin-left: -22px;
 background-position: 0 -108px;
 opacity: 0.8;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 8060;
}

#fancybox-loading div {
 width: 44px;
 height: 44px;
 background: url('../images/fancybox_loading.gif') center center no-repeat;
}

.fancybox-close {
 position: absolute;
 top: -18px;
 right: -18px;
 width: 36px;
 height: 36px;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 8040;
}

.fancybox-nav {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 width: 40%;
 height: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
 background: transparent url('../images/blank.gif'); /* helps IE */
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
 z-index: 8040;
}

.fancybox-prev {
 left: 0;
}

.fancybox-next {
 right: 0;
}

.fancybox-nav span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 width: 36px;
 height: 34px;
 margin-top: -18px;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 8040;
 visibility: hidden;
}

.fancybox-prev span {
 left: 10px;
 background-position: 0 -36px;
}

.fancybox-next span {
 right: 10px;
 background-position: 0 -72px;
}

.fancybox-nav:hover span {
 visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-tmp {
 position: absolute;
 top: -99999px;
 left: -99999px;
 visibility: hidden;
 max-width: 99999px;
 max-height: 99999px;
 overflow: visible !important;
}

/* Overlay helper */

.fancybox-lock {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    width: auto;
}

.fancybox-lock body {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

.fancybox-lock-test {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}

.fancybox-overlay {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: none;
 z-index: 8010;
 background: url('../images/fancybox_overlay.png');
}

.fancybox-overlay-fixed {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}

.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
 overflow: auto;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* Title helper */

.fancybox-title {
 visibility: hidden;
 font: normal 13px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 text-shadow: none;
 z-index: 8050;
}

.fancybox-opened .fancybox-title {
 visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-title-float-wrap {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 50%;
 margin-bottom: -35px;
 z-index: 8050;
 text-align: center;
}

.fancybox-title-float-wrap .child {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: -100%;
 padding: 2px 20px;
 background: transparent; /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
         border-radius: 15px;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #222;
 color: #FFF;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 24px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.fancybox-title-outside-wrap {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 10px;
 color: #fff;
}

.fancybox-title-inside-wrap {
 padding-top: 10px;
}

.fancybox-title-over-wrap {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #000;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

/*Retina graphics!*/
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){

 #fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
  background-image: url('../images/fancybox_sprite@2x.png');
  background-size: 44px 152px; /*The size of the normal image, half the size of the hi-res image*/
 }

 #fancybox-loading div {
  background-image: url('../images/fancybox_loading@2x.gif');
  background-size: 24px 24px; /*The size of the normal image, half the size of the hi-res image*/
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://yourjavascript.com/71835177135/jquery-fancybox.js"></script>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="iframe.html">Iframe</a>
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to upgrade to v3?

Comment: @Janis do you mean this? http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/

Comment: Of course......

Comment: The code developed last time, I just make changes on this and wonder why something like this happened. That's mean if I wanna solve this issue, I need to change the code to v3?

Answer (score 1):

1st screen - scrollbars have appeared and the explanation is very simple - the script tries to calculate height of the iframed page and tries to match iframe size. Calculation is quite tricky and sometimes it works well, sometimes not so, it has been improved in v3.

On 2nd screen - you are developing locally and the script can not access contents of the iframed page, therefore it fails and simply resizes iframe to fit the screen.

Comment: I still have same issue after changed to v3

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: Have you tried on real page? Usually, the problem is that first element (heading) has top-margin that pushes content down.